# Testing Angular 4 (previously Angular 2) Apps with Jasmine - Udemy Course

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Someone please share the latest Angular version codes for this course, since it is written in Angular 4.

My current Angular version 14 is not compatible to complete this course, so I need the compatible codes to complete this course.

Answer (score -1):

This course is written in Angular 4, so anyone working with the latest Angular version cannot execute the author-shared code(testing-demo) correctly. So to overcome this here I'm providing the compatible codes.

My specs are,

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___ 
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | | 
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | | 
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 14.2.10
Node: 16.17.0
Package Manager: npm 8.15.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.2.12
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.10
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.10
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.10
@angular/cli                    14.2.10
@schematics/angular             14.2.10
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.7.4
```

Please refer to the following URL to get,

**"Section 2: Unit Testing Angular Apps source code"** - [testing-demo](https://github.com/therimuthuselvam/public-workspace/tree/main/angular-app/testing-demo)

**"Section 3: Integration Testing source code"** - [integration-testing-demo](https://github.com/therimuthuselvam/public-workspace/tree/main/angular-app/integration-testing-demo)